# How can I use tsvector on a string with numbers?

Tags: postgresql, tsvector

I would like to use a postgres tsquery on a column that has strings that all contain numbers, like this:

```
FRUIT-239476234
```

If I try to make a tsquery out of this:

```
select to_tsquery('FRUIT-239476234');
```

What I get is:

```
'fruit' & '-239476234'
```

I want to be able to search by just the numeric portion of this value like so:

```
239476234
```

It seems that it is unable to match this because it is interpreting my hyphen as a "negative sign" and doesn't think `239476234` matches `-239476234`.  How can I tell postgres to treat *all* of my characters as text and not try to be smart about numbers and hyphens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by the text search parser, which is not configurable (short of writing your own parser in C, which is supported).

The simplest solution is to pre-process all search strings by replacing `-` with a space.

Comment: I think he could use the default parser and add a dictionary to strip off the hyphens.  That is not exactly easy, but surely easier than creating a new parser.  He could maybe even use contrib/dict_int as a model.

Comment: @jjanes I guess I didn't make it clear enough that I am *not* suggesting to write a new parser. I am thinking of using `replace` on the strings *before* applying the FTS functions.

Comment: Right, the dictionary is just another option.  It is easier to set up than a new parser, harder to set up than using REPLACE.  And I think it is cleaner than REPLACE because it doesn't require the user to remember to manually insert the REPLACE everywhere they need.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up what doing and it works!  I wish there were a way to just configure it, looks like that may be coming in the future though.

Answer (score 5):

An answer from the future.  Once version 13 of PostgreSQL is released, you will be able to do use the [dict_int module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/dict-int.html) to do this.

```
create extension dict_int ;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY intdict (MAXLEN = 100, ABSVAL=true);
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION english ALTER MAPPING FOR int WITH intdict;
select to_tsquery('FRUIT-239476234');

      to_tsquery       
-----------------------
 'fruit' & '239476234'
```

But you would probably be better off creating your own TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY as well as copying the 'english' CONFIGURATION and modifying the copy, rather than modifying the default ones in place.  Otherwise you have the risk that upgrading will silently lose your changes.

If you don't want to wait for v13, you could back-patch [this change](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=806eb92c018102da9514443ad19160c7b1841062) and compile into your own version of the extension for a prior server.

Comment: Future me will be very excited for this when it comes out, thanks for the info!

Comment: But I want the same behavior as for hyphenated words, where it generates a compound lexem as well, so that something like "DN-12-40" could be matched whole, not 3 separate tokens... As I understand it, this would require a implemeting a custom parser in C, so that the numbers are not recognized as Signed integer token types at all.

Comment: The future is now, and I am thankful that this works!